# MathJax and MathML displayed 'Unknown node type: declare' on IE

Tags: html, mathjax, mathml

I'm studying on MathML using MathJax since for displaying mathematic expressions on IE and Chrome. Any way... when I try to using 'declare' tag like follwing,

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Mixed Markup</title>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        MathML: {
            extensions: ["content-mathml.js"]
        }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" async
        src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

```
<body>
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <declare>
            <ci> A </ci>
            <vector>
               <ci> a </ci>
               <ci> b </ci>
               <ci> c </ci>
            </vector>
        </declare>
    </math>
</body>
```

IE shows it as

`Unknown node type: declare`

So... what can I do to use `declare` tag??

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<declare>` element is deprecated in MathML, cf. [the spec](https://www.w3.org/Math/draft-spec/mathml.html#chapter4_contm.deprecated) and MathJax's Content MathML extension does not support it; the newer `<share>` element (replacing `declare`) is supported.

Comment: Soooo thank you ! Can you give an address for that? I couldn't see that in MathML's Content Markup page... http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/chapter4.html#contm.declare

Comment: You are linking to the MathML 2 spec while in my answer I point to the current MathML 3 spec (the editor's draft to be precise).